# Where is my PDF printer printing my documents?

Tags: drivers, printing, pdf

Running Kubuntu 17.10.

I installed printer-driver-cups-pdf.

When I print from any application (native ones like Kate or others like Firefox), there is a default 'Print to file' printer and a 'PDF' printer like this:

[image]

I can select 'Print to file' printer and choose the filename and folder where to save the file.

But when I choose 'PDF' printer, it asks for nothing. It just shows a window as if it is sending pages to a printer. Then the window disappears. I am not able to get a screenshot of this window as it disappears pretty fast.

But where are the files? They are not in ~, ~/Downloads, /tmp or ~/Documents

Comment: Are you using the system print dialogue, printing directly from Firefox or Chromium or what?

Comment: @chili555 I have edited the question to answer your question. Sorry, could have given it earlier

Comment: @George Thanks for the suggestion. But I have hundreds of PDFs with similar names. It would be a nightmear to do a `find /`. :)

Comment: you can print a file with a unique name like `searchForThisFileOnly.pdf`, then do the search `find / -iname 'searchForThisFileOnly.pdf' `

Comment: Btw, for me the pdf printer always saves the files under `~/Documents/`

Comment: @bistoco it does not ask me for a filename when I print using PDF as a printer.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot ? that will be more clarifying

Comment: @bistoco Added a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69120/discussion-between-bistoco-and-deshmukh).

Comment: Look for a directory in your home named 'PDF'

Comment: @CharlesGreen Perfect. Thanks. The files are indeed in the PDF folder. bistoco suggested the same thing a few minutes ago on the private chat. I have asked him to give it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to create a directory called 'PDF' in your home folder, or edit `/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf` where you can put `${HOME}/Desktop` or any other path you want (and have access to).

*Sumary of responses from this page :
http://keeshink.blogspot.cl/2009/01/where-does-cups-pdf-put-my-pdf-file.html

Comment: Is not there a way to set it up for a user? I generally avoid editing system files. The link you provided also does not mention per user customization.